# Is it possible to import specific class from project propreties in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, svn, r.java-file

I have 2 projects. First project need to include second. When I copy sources from second project to first I need to modify manually import path to R.java file.
The problem is that I need to use SVN external link connection between this 2 projects, that is mean, one project (the bigger one) will take sources from another through svn and should be able to use it without any modifications.

If I would be able to specify R.java file path anywhere in project properties  it will resolve my problem by changing manually that path.
Need to specify that package name of these 2 projects are different.

Another solution to resolve this problem also would be accepted.
Thank you.

Comment: project import in the IDE you are working?

Comment: I'm woriking in eclipse.

Comment: Why can't the first project reference the second project as a library project? Then you don't need to change any paths or any of that stuff.

Comment: did you mean second project made as a .jar file? This is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the project to the build path of the other project, properties-Java buildpath-select project Tab-Add your project.

[image]